# How do I Prevent Httrack From Downloading the Same File Again?

Tags: html, css, scripting, download

I am using httrack to download this website:
http://4minutearticles.com/

However, the problem is that the author has link back to the main page on every page of his website

For example http://4minutearticles.com/ext/

The Parent Directory Link Redirect to the main page
and the software start downloading again

How do I prevent this loop from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the answer to the question on the link provided below:

"I have duplicate files!What's going on?"

Link: http://www.httrack.com/html/faq.html#Q1b11

Also have a look at the "Filters:Advanced" on following link:

http://www.httrack.com/html/filters.html

It may help you on your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use filters to stop HTTRACK from downloading same files or folders. You can do this by  clicking the "Set options" button in front of the "Preferences and Mirror options" label, then opening the "Scan Rules" tab and then the "Exclude links" button to set the rules as you want.

Comment: Yeah, did that but it didn't work out. Still looping at the http://www.4minutearticles.com/ext/images

Answer (score 0):

> This is generally the case for top indexes (index.html and
>   index-2.html).
>
> This is a common issue, but that can not be easily avoided!
>
> For example, http://www.foobar.com/ and
>   http://www.foobar.com/index.html might be the same pages. But if links
>   in the website refers both to http://www.foobar.com/ and
>   http://www.foobar.com/index.html, these two pages will be caught. And
>   because http://www.foobar.com/ must have a name, as you may want to
>   browse the website locally (the / would give a directory listing, NOT
>   the index itself!), HTTrack must find one. Therefore, two index.html
>   will be produced, one with the -2 to show that the file had to be
>   renamed.
>
> It might be a good idea to consider that http://www.foobar.com/ and
>   http://www.foobar.com/index.html are the same links, to avoid
>   duplicate files, isn't it? NO, because the top index (/) can refer to
>   ANY filename, and if index.html is generally the default name,
>   index.htm can be choosen, or index.php3, mydog.jpg, or anything you
>   may imagine. (some webmasters are really crazy)
>
> Note: In some rare cases, duplicate data files can be found when the
>   website redirect to another file. This issue should be rare, and might
>   be avoided using filters.

See also: [Updating a project](http://httrack.kauler.com/help/Updating_a_project)